# Output Relative URL

Tags: templating

I need to output the relative URL for the current page for a GA event label.
According to Craft 3 docs, it seems like rootRelativeUrl() as in:

```
{% relative = entry.rootRelativeUrl() %}
```

should do the job but it generates and 'Calling unknown method' error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

`{% set relativeUrl = craft.app.request.url %}`

Otherwise, and as a general example of using Craft helper functions...

`rootRelativeUrl` is actually a method on the UrlHelper class, thus it's not available on elements I don't think.

Try this:

```
{# Use any Craft "helper" classes in your Twig templates by creating them #}
{% set urlHelper = create(
    "craft\\helpers\\UrlHelper"
) %}
{# You can then call any of their methods, e.g.: #}
{{ set relative = urlHelper.rootRelativeUrl(entry.url) }}
```

(or you could get the url from `craft.request.url` for example)

(snippet pinched from from https://nystudio107.com/blog/cutting-the-cord-removing-plugins)

Comment: Thanks! You put me on the right track. This worked: {% set relativeUrl = craft.app.request.url %}

Comment: Well LOL yes, that's the easier way.  I got side tracked by the rootRelativeUrl thing.  Also I think in Craft 2 the request url was the full, not relative url...but I might be mis remembering.